# Why do I consistently get an incomplete object when deserializing a SOAP response?

Tags: java, xml, spring, soap

I have a Java 8 Spring Boot, formerly WebLogic, application that utilizes Apache CXF and Apache Tomcat. It has several SOAP endpoints that I want to write Cucumber scenarios to perform integration testing with. These scenarios make a HTTP call to a particular endpoint using Spring's RestTemplate to validate the headers as well as portions of the response. To this end, I want to deserialize the server's XML response into a POJO, but I cannot get the object to deserialize properly.

Thus far, the best I can get is an ResponseEntity with a body (the deserialized server response object) that contains just a tiny portion of the response I expect. For instance, I have POJO (which is the same class that the endpoint returns) that looks like this:

```
    public class MyServerReply implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private ReplyInfo replyInfo;
    private String transactionId;
    private String version;
    private String environment;
    private ErrorStatus errorStatus;

    public MyServerReply() {
        // constructor stuff
    }

    // getters and setters go here
    }
```

Consistently, I will have exactly a single field populated as expected, while every other field is either empty or 0. Using an HTTP client like Insomnia or Postman with an identical request body, I can tell that the server is not returning this incomplete response. Likewise, consider the code which I am using to make the HTTP call:

```
    public ResponseEntity<MyServerReply> call_getReplyInfo(String arg1, String arg2) {
        String soapRequest = String.format(SampleRequestBodies.getReplyInfo, arg1, arg2);

        HttpEntity<MyServerReply> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(soapRequest, headers);
        return restTemplate.exchange(myServerUrl, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, MyServerReply.class);
    }
```

I can get the expected response if I modified this method to return a ResponseEntity instead, but, obviously, this gives me a String body rather than the POJO I need.

The endpoint for this particular example looks like this:

```
    @WebMethod(operationName = "getReplyInfo")
    @WebResult(name = "getReplyInfoMessage", targetNamespace = "http://myNameSpace.com/myApp")
    public MyServerReply getReplyInfo(InfoRequest reqObj) {
    try { 
        return myApi.getReplyInfo(reqObj); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // exception handling goes here
    }
    }
```

And the server response (with field values omitted) is as follows:

```
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns2:getReplyInfoResponse
            xmlns:ns2="http://myNameSpace.com/myApp">
            <ns2:getReplyInfoMessage>
                <replyInfo>
                    // bunch of response stuff
                </replyInfo>
                <transId></transId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <environment>local</environment>
                <errorStatus>
                    // error status fields go here
                    <uuid>97983440-6c7b-4ca9-a139-328f2de7da1c</uuid> <--bizarrely, this is consistently the only field that is populated when deserializing
                </errorStatus>
            </ns2:getReplyInfoMessage>
        </ns2:getReplyInfoResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

As a note, the original WSDL files for this application have been lost to time.

I have attempted several fixes. I tried adding various javax Xml annotations including @XmlRootElement, @XmlType, and combinations of both like so:

```
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


    @XmlType(name = "getReplyInfoMessage")
    public class MyServerReply {
```

I also tried annotating all of the fields of the above POJO with @XmlElement, as well as just the getters with no success. This process was also done for the ErrorStatus & ReplyInfo classes to no avail.

I tried to add the a MessageConverter, specifically MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter from jackson-dataformat-xml, to the restTemplate and get the same incomplete result.

While I would prefer if the ResponseEntity was of the same type as the POJO I am attempting to deserialize, I also couldn't successfully deserialize the response generally speaking. Using the XMLMapper from the same jackson library with the following setup, I still get an incomplete object:

```
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(myServerUrl, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);

    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    // This is required, since the response includes the outermost Envelope and Body elements and these elements are a part of the POJO I am deserializing to
    xmlMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    // reply is not null, but it is mostly full of empty fields, excluding the uuid field for whatever reason
    reply = xmlMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), MyServerReply.class);
```

Finally, while I would prefer not to use this approach, I also have attempted to marshal/unmarshal with JAXB. However, in this case, my request object is not understood by the server. I can include the details of that attempt in this post upon request, but will initially omit it since it is a different sort of error.